# how can we shoot tv show so "tarak mehta ka ulta chasma" it will look like "house of card"?

Tags: video, camera

Hi stackexchange folks.

I need your help.

I want to know that if we want to shoot TV show as following like "house of card" TV show video quality. then what are the changes or steps we need to take. we need to make changes in cameras or video editing ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tell us what you are using now. Cameras and your editing process and what programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see four basic differences (in what I believe is the correct priority order):

1. Lighting.  The lighting on Kevin Spacey is classic three-point lighting with warm fronts, a 2:1 key/fill ratio, and cold back/rim/hair light.  Proper 3-point lighting is the biggest difference between the pro look of episodic television and the amateur look of most YouTube videos.

   2. Resolution.  House of Cards is shot in 5K and mastered in 4K resolution.  You can see it even in greatly scaled down images.
   3. Sensor size/shallow depth of field.  With a large enough image sensor and a large enough lens aperture, it's possible to get crisp focus on the subject and beautiful blur in the background, which as you rightly observe, make you really pay attention to the subject instead of all the many distractions surrounding them.
   4. Set design and wardrobe.  The muted colors (and lower light levels) of the background and the dark suit again focus the viewer on the face and hands (key dramatic communicators) of the actor.  Contrast that with loud colored clothing and bright walls, the eye is overwhelmed with too many subjects to deal with.

Slumdog Millionaire got all this right.  You can, too!